# call a generic static class method php

Tags: php, oop, templates

I would like to write a generic method that refers to a generic class (but the same method) in php.

```
class A {

    public static function Dox(){
    }

}

class B {

    public static function Dox(){
    }

}

class C{

    public static function Include($class){
    $result = $class::Dox(); //instead of 2 methods => A::Dox and B::Dox
    }

}
```

I get an error. 
any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does [`call_user_func`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php) work?

```
class A {
    public static function Dox() {
    }
}

class B {
    public static function Dox() {
    }
}

class C {
    public static function Include($class) {
        $result = call_user_func(array($class, "Dox"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`include` is a [keyword](http://docs.php.net/reserved.keywords). Rename your method to foo(), bar() or anything that is not a keyword.

e.g.

```
<?php
class A {
    public static function Dox() { return 'A::Dox'; }
}

class B {
    public static function Dox() { return 'B::Dox'; }
}

class C {
    public static function foo($class) {
        $result = $class::Dox();
        echo 'result: ', $result, "\n";
    }
}

foreach( array('A','B') as $c ) {
    C::foo($c);
}
```

prints

```
result: A::Dox
result: B::Dox
```

Answer (score 0):

Include keyword "spesific keyword".

Try it:

```
public static function IncludeXXX(){...}
```